# Azure WAAD/WIF C# / REST

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, sap, wif, claims-based-identity

I need to authenticate users with WS-Fed/SSO.
But how can I get user roles from f.e. SAP to authenticate them with WIF and use defined roles?
Is there something like C#/REST Api available? Or how to connect the ID-Prov. with 3rd party SAP system?
Or need I sync them with through WAAD? But how?
Short explaination:
User -> WebService -> ID-Prov. -> 3rd-Party -> ACCESS

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to use Federated Identity with Multiple Partners and Windows Azure Access Control Service. as long as you handle the claim mapping rules programmatically azure ACS can integrated with any custom identity provider. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446534.aspx